# Excel formula to populate Data based on a series or rules run on a different cell in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-365

I need to populate a cell with some combination of data from another cell.  Here's what my data looks like (sorry I can't post images):Column A = NameColumn B = TeamColumn C = Short Name

I'm trying to populate the Short Name based on a series of rules applied to the Name (column A).  I have some of it working. So here's what I'm hoping to get to:

this is the rule that's working: - If the name contains a ":" I'm populating the cell with the first 4 characters after that [IFERROR(B2&""&MID(A2, FIND(":", A2,1)+1,4),"")].  If it doesn't find the :, it's leaving Column C blank.  This was working perfectly until a new need was introduced...

So now Column C would be populated based on one of 3 things:

1. Exactly what's happening now.  So if : exists populate column C based on the formula above
2. If the : doesn't exist I need to inspect Column A for "(ENH)".  If (ENH) exists, I need column C populated with everything that's displayed in column A. If it exists, (ENH) will always be the first 5 characters displayed in column A.
3. If : or (ENH) doesn't exist, Column C stays blank

Using my real data, at the end of the day Column C will display one of the following 3 things, displayed in the order of my rules above:

1. Gold O&M
2. (ENH) UI Refactor
3. BLANK

Comment: You can use `ISNUMBER` to check if `SEARCH()` returns a valid index.  With that in mind, given that you don't show the values for columns A and B, does `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":", A2)), B2&" "&MID(A2,SEARCH(":", A2)+1, 4), IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("(ENH)", A2)), A2, ""))` work correctly?  If not, might you please [edit] your question to use [table markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997) to show your example input data?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to populate the C "Short Name" column:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":", A2)), B2&" "&MID(A2,SEARCH(":", A2)+1, 4), IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("(ENH)", A2)), A2, ""))
```

This results in the following table:

| NameColumn | TeamColumn | Short Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foobar:O&M | Gold | Gold O&M |
| (ENH) UI Refactor | whatever1 | (ENH) UI Refactor |
| Flubber | whatever2 |  |

Notes:

- [`FIND()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) is case-sensitive while [`SEARCH()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) is not.  I used `FIND()` for `"(ENH)"` because it seemed as though you wanted an exact match. If `"(enh)"` should also match, use `SEARCH()`.
- [`ISNUMBER(...)`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) can be used to check whether `SEARCH()` and `FIND()` returned a valid index instead of `#VALUE!`, and thus whether the search text was found.  `NOT(ISERROR(...))` could also be used.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did exactly what I needed and taught me along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little info given without posting samples this would work using Office 365:
`=IFERROR(B2&" "&LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A2,":",1),5),IF(LEFT(A2,5)="(ENH)",A2,""))`

*TEXTAFTER checks for a (nth) delimiter and shows the text after that. This is (if you ask me) easier to read than MID. But basically it does the same in this case.*

If you need a better answer follow dbc's advice to post data as markdown table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  DBC, work perfectly for me but beyond the formula, I learned something with the markdown table.  I'm not a regular poster here so I'll grow!